# Detect data type from XML string using python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have some XML tagged string as follows.

```
<Processor>AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4400+ 2.31 GHz</Processor>
<ClockSpeed>2.31</ClockSpeed>
<NumberOfCores>2</NumberOfCores>
<InstalledMemory>2.00</InstalledMemory>
<OperatingSystem>Windows 7 Professional</OperatingSystem>
```

How can I detect the data type automatically using python?
For example, "AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4400+ 2.31 GHz" -> string, "2.31" -> float, and on.

I need this functionality as I need to make SQLite Table out of the XML data something like

```
CREATE table ABC (Processor string, ClockSpeed float ... )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to try various types in precise sequence, defaulting to `str` if none of those work.  E.g.:

```
def what_type(s, possible_types=((int, [0]), (float, ()))):
    for t, xargs in possible_types:
        try: t(s, *xargs)
        except ValueError: pass
        else: return t
    return str
```

This is particularly advisable, of course, when you to use want exactly the same syntax conventions as Python -- e.g., accept `'0x7e'` as `int` as well as `'126'`, and so on.  If you need different syntax conventions, then you should instead perform parsing on string `s`, whether via REs or by other means.

Comment: How can I return "int", instead of <type  'int'>?

Comment: Add a third value to the tuples in the `possible_types` array which is a string representation of that type; then modify the for loop to be `for t, xargs, stype:` and then `return stype`.

Comment: @Amber's suggestion is good and very general, but `return t.__name__` will work if Python's exact type names are good for you.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the kinds of formats you expect, you could use regexes to detect floats and ints, and then assume that anything which can't be parsed into a number is a string, like so:

```
import re

FLOAT_RE = re.compile(r'^(\d+\.\d*|\d*\.\d+)$')
INT_RE = re.compile(r'^\d+$')

# ... code to get xml value into a variable ...

if FLOAT_RE.match(xml_value):
    value_type = 'float'
elif INT_RE.match(xml_value):
    value_type = 'int'
else:
    value_type = 'string'
```

This is just a very basic stab at it - there are more complex formats for expressing numbers that are possible; if you think you might expect some of the more complex formats you'd have to expand this to make it work properly in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is a good HTML/XML parser:

```
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/
```

I'm not entirely sure if it can convert data by type given an xsd/xsl, but it can detect encoding, so there might be a start.